# What kind of Python assignment is this called?

Tags: python, variables

I saw this in a Pygame tutorial:

```
size = width, height = 600,400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
```

I understand width, height being set to 600, 400 respectively, but what is size?  That's one variable.  Thanks.

Comment: For things like this, it's usually best to play around with the Python interpreter to figure it out yourself. In any case, a comma delimited list (with or without parentheses) is a tuple.

Comment: python is amazing, you could try pycharms ide for enjoying it

Comment: It's called tuple packing and unpacking

Answer (score 5):

size is assigned the tuple (600,400).

```
>>> size = width, height = 600,400
>>> size
(600, 400)
>>> width
600
>>> height
400
```

Comment: So Python "knows" to make this a tuple?

Comment: @johnny: Yes, because it **is** actually a tuple. What creates a tuple isn't the parentheses, it's the comma (exception: empty tuples can be written as `()`)

Comment: yes and you can do a lot of other cooler things in python too like assigning multiple values at once  or assigning consecutive values. As Kevin mentioned, Interpreter is your best friend to understand them.

Comment: Yep.. the magic here is that 600, 400 creates a tuple and the width, height assignment automatically unpacks the tuple.  The assignment of the tuple to size is actually fairly straight-forward.

Comment: Although, you need to be a little careful here @viothos.  `width, height` actually isn't a tuple since it is on the left of the (rightmost) assignment.  However, `600, 400` is a tuple.